# Google ChromeCast Playlist from Android Device

Tags: android, chromecast

I'm using a [sample app for the RemotePlaybackClient](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MediaRouter/RemotePlayback) from [@commonsware](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) to play a video from a url to Google **ChromeCast** dongle, the app works like a charm but I would like to implement a playlist, any idea how to send a playlist to ChromeCast from an Android device?
As usual, I don't need code, just links, tutorials, etc... Tks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a custom receiver?

If so, you can pass a json to such receiver with your playlist and manage that list with a playback state.

Answer (score 1):

you might try looking at "mediaList" object [here](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android/blob/master/src/com/google/sample/cast/refplayer/browser/VideoProvider.java).  Thats your playlist object.

This is a totally different project (not mediaRouter api but ccl instead) that i used because i wanted to implement a playlist and wanted to NOT take on my own receiver app. I wanted to see whether the default receiver could collaborate with an existing github sender sample - altered slightly to manipulate both a playList implemented in the "mediaList" AND to send appropriate and successive PLAY instructions to the default recieiver app when that app's state as relayed in normal "consumer" message traffic indicated state=ready.

```
D/ccl_VideoCastManager(31057): onApplicationStatusChanged() reached: Ready To Cast
```

So, when the default receiver fires the "ready" message, the senderApp can just call getNext to return an entry from "mediaList" and then send a "play(mediaInfo.entry)" to the default receiver.

**onApplicationStatusChanged()** is the [interface](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/Cast.Listener.html) used by the ccl to commmunicate/ sync player state between the local/remote players. When the default-remote-state changes to "ready to cast" you can use "VideoCastManager" and its base class to select the next MediaInfo entry and format a message for the remote to play it...

```
this.startCastControllerActivity(this.mContext, nextMediaInfo, 0, true);
```

code above from sender/ccl base tells the receiver to play the item that the sender has determine is next from list.

Note : i was advised to implement the playlist on a custom receiver app that i would write. Im not that ambitious and found a very simple hack on the sender/ccl classes that was reliable enough for me.

Comment: The issue with having the playlist in the sender is that if your sender gets disconnected, the notion of playlist is gone, so as long as you are the only person connected and as long as you can be sure your sender is not going to be connected, you are fine; if any of these two is violated, then your approach fails.

Comment: Yes the disconnect is a bit of an issue. If the controller device's goes to sleep after 1 minute but the aggregate length of the items in the playList is greater than 1 minute then playList plays interrupt shortly after the display screen goes dark on the controller device. Saved so much work not having to write a custom receiver that i will live with it for awhile.